# ResultSet does not refelect updated list after insertRow

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle12c

I tried to search about it but not satisfied with the results. Basically, the issue I am facing is, when I insert row using `ResultSetName.insertRow()`, record is successfully added to database table but it does not reflected in my ResultSet, means my resultSet does not show the record added using `insertRow()`.
My resultSet is `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` and  `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE`.
I am using

> DBMS version : Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.2.0 64 bit
>
> JDBC version : JDBC driver version is 12.1.0.1.0

Code snippet :

```
rs.moveToInsertRow();
rs.updateString("COLUMNNAME1","QWERTY");
rs.updateString("COLUMNNAME2","QWERTY DATA");
rs.insertRow();
```

**SOLUTION :**

My other PC was using JDBC Driver 12.1.0.2.0 and it is reflecting the inserted row into result set.However, following results create confusion,

Code snippet :

```
DatabaseMetaData met = conn.getMetaData();
if(met.ownInsertsAreVisible(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE)) {
    System.out.println("ownInsertsAreVisible : true");
}
else {
    System.out.println("ownInsertsAreVisible : false");
}

if(met.insertsAreDetected(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE)) {
    System.out.println("insertsAreDetected : true");
}
else {
    System.out.println("insertsAreDetected : false");
}
```

**OUTPUT :** 
ownInsertsAreVisible : false 
insertsAreDetected : false

This is strange but it working for me now with new version thanks.

Comment: JDBC implementations are allowed to not have the changes reflected in the result set. What does [`DatabaseMetaData.ownInsertsAreVisible`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#ownInsertsAreVisible-int-) return?

Comment: Note that _"Oracle DBMS and JDBC7 version."_ is not valid version information, please post the version of Oracle and the version of the driver you are using.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I have two PCs installed with netbeans both of them are returning 'false' for DatabaseMetaData.ownInsertsAreVisible(). However, in one PC it was able to reflect the changes in  my resultSet and the other one was not able to do the same.

Comment: Then would check if for both the version of driver and database are the same, and also check the other related database metadata methods (eg `insertsAreDetected`)

Comment: My DBMS is "Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.2.0 64 bit" and JDBC version is "JDBC driver version is 12.1.0.1.0".

Comment: Please include in your question the code you are using to test if the resultSet shows the record added.

Comment: Thanks for the help developer. It was issue with JDBC driver. I have updated the solution.

Comment: Instead of editing you **question** with a solution, please post it as an **answer**. It is perfectly fine to answer your own question. Interesting that the `DatabaseMetaData` of the driver is not consistent with its behavior though ;)

Answer (score 0):

My other PC was using JDBC Driver **12.1.0.2.0** and it is reflecting the inserted row into result set.However, following results create confusion,

**Code snippet :**

```
DatabaseMetaData met = conn.getMetaData();
if(met.ownInsertsAreVisible(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE)) {
    System.out.println("ownInsertsAreVisible : true");
}
else {
    System.out.println("ownInsertsAreVisible : false");
}

if(met.insertsAreDetected(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE)) {
    System.out.println("insertsAreDetected : true");
}
else {
    System.out.println("insertsAreDetected : false");
}
```

**OUTPUT :** 
ownInsertsAreVisible : false 
insertsAreDetected : false

This is strange but it is working for me now with new version thanks.